# Entity Framework DbContext mapping property based on discriminator column and id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

*Background*
I'm working on a system which was designed with a plugin architecture to allow for multiple data stores (SQL Server, Firebird, MySQL).

This plugin architecture is fairly complex and seems to be an attempt to write ADO.NET from scratch. Over time, the 'plugin' functionality of using databases other than SQL Server has been removed. I'm looking into converting the data access portion of this project from the legacy framework to Entity Framework 5.0 DbContext. ***I'm trying to not modify the database to avoid data conversions for existing customers.***

I have experience with Fluent NHibernate, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to use EF DbContext's Fluent API to resolve my current project goals. I know the Fluent API is generally intended for Code-First development, but I'd like to use it in this case for maintenance reasons.

*The problem*
I have many tables which contain a `ParentTable` and `ParentId` column. ParentTable is a `short` and ParentId is an `int` (not sure that matters).

I have an abstract base object, which current just has an Int32 property for `Id`.

What I'd like to do is define an enum to be mapped to the `ParentTable` property and have these objects with parents return an instance of the base object based on the `ParentTable` enum discriminator.  What is the best approach to go about doing this in EF DbContext?  If I need to have some sort of extension method or repository method called `GetParent`, I'm fine with that but I'd rather have this done automatically by EF's mappings if possible.

Here's an example (No, I haven't created the enum for the table associations yet):

```
public class Person : BaseObject, IHasParentProperties
{
    // ... removed other properties
    public short ParentTable { get; internal set; }
    public int ParentId { get; internal set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public BaseObject Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose `ParentTable` in the `Person` object is a short which maps to the future enum value of `TableMapping.Client` and `ParentId` is `333`, is it possible to configure the mapping to load `Parent` as a `Client` object based on the table discriminator *and* id? There will always be only a single parent, but the parent could be one of any of ten different objects.

In Fluent NHibernate, if I remember correctly I had accomplished this same task with some variation of the References discriminators (taken from [here](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping)):

```
ReferencesAny(x => x.Author)
  .EntityTypeColumn("Type")
  .EntityIdentifierColumn("Id")
  .IdentityType<int>();
```

It's been a while, but I remember the experience being on par to my current experience with EF.

I'd love to normalize the database and rewrite most of this from scratch, but I'm trying to make everything as easy as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: You should be half way there now that Entity Framework 5 supports enum properties.

Comment: @Mike I was compiling against .NET 4.0, and it only supports enums in 4.5. I have a method to look up the parent object in a switch case using the enum I've created, but I'm trying to determine whether this can be done automatically via mappings.